# How to interpolate a variable into a regex-pattern in the regex part of a substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, interpolation

What do I have to change here to make it work?

```
my $str = "start middle end";
my $regex = / start ( .+ ) end /;
$str.=subst( / <$regex> /, { $0 } ); # dies: Use of Nil in string context
say "[$str]";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that interpolating a regex into another regex via the `<$regex>` syntax will not install a result in the match variable. There's two ways to get around this:

- The easiest way is to just use the regex directly in subst, i.e. `$str .= subst($regex, { $0 });`
- Give the interpolated regex an explicit name and access the result via that, i.e. `$str .= subst( / <foo=$regex> /, { $<foo>[0] });`

Both of these should work fine.

Comment: +1 I feel like I should have known it already but I didn't: you can just drop a regex var into `< ... >` and have it function as an inserted regex.  And to think I've been generating complex escaped strings to dump in with `<{ ... }>`.  D'oh.

Comment: From the "traps to avoid" [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#%3C%7B%24x%7D%3E_vs_%24%28%24x%29%3A_Implicit_EVAL):
Internally <{…}> EVAL-s the given string inside an anonymous regex, while $(…) lexically interpolates the given string. So <{…}> immediately breaks with more complicated inputs.

and later

> Therefore, try not to use <{}> unless you really need EVAL.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71057626/7270649