# Escaping metacharacters in a Raku regex (like Perl's quotemeta() or \Q...\E)?

Tags: regex, escaping, raku, modifier, quotemeta

How can I escape metacharacters in a Raku regex the way I would with Perl's [quotemeta function](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#quotemeta) (`\Q..\E`)?

That is, the Perl code

```perl
my $sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
my $substring = 'quick.*?fox';
$sentence =~ s{$substring}{big bad wolf};
print $sentence
```

treats each of `.`, `*`, and `?` as metacharacters and thus prints `The big bad wolf jumped over the lazy dog`.  But if I change the second-to-last line to `$sentence =~ s{\Q$substring\E}{big bad wolf};`, then Perl treats `.*?` as literal characters and thus prints `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`.

How can I treat characters literally in a Raku regex?

Comment: Note: I split this question off from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70996158/perl-dot-matches-newline-s-modifier-in-raku) that asked two separate questions at once (to make both questions clearer and more searchable).  Others are of course welcome to answer, but it's not really an "active" question in that I already knew the answer when posting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Your question's answer:

You can treat characters in a Raku regex literally by surrounding them with quotes (e.g., `'.*?'`) or by using using regular variable interpolation (e.g., `$substring` inside the regex where `$substring` is a string contaning metacharacters).

Thus, to translate the Perl program with `\Q...\E` from your question into Raku, you could write:

```raku
my $sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
my $substring = 'quick.*?fox';
$sentence ~~ s/$substring/big bad wolf/;
print $sentence
```

This would treat `.*?` as literal characters, not metacharacters.  If you wanted to avoid interpolation with literal text rather than a variable, you could change the substitution regex to `s/quick '.*?' fox/big bad wolf/`.  Conversely, if you want to use the `$substring` variable as part of a regex (that is, if you **do** want `.*?` to be metacharacters) you'd need to to change the substitution regex to `s/<$substring>/big bad wolf/`.  For more details, you can consult the [Rexex interpolation docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_interpolation).

## How you could have found this answer without waiting for SO

What should you do when you don't know how to do something in Raku?  Asking either on the [IRC channel](https://raku.org/community/irc) or here on Stack Overflow is an option – and asking a clear Q on SO has the benefit of making the answer more searchable for anyone else who has the same question in the future.

But both IRC and SO are asynchronous – so you'll probably need to wait a bit for an answer. There are other ways that folks interested in Raku frequently get good/great answers to their questions more *easily* and *quickly* than they could from IRC/SO, and the remainder of this answer provides some guidance about these ways. (I've numbered the steps in the general order I'd recommend, but there's no reason you *need* to follow that order).

### Easily get better answers more quickly than asking SO Qs

#### Step -1: Let Raku answer the question for you

Raku strives to have awesome error messages, and sometimes you'll be lucky enough to try something in a way that doesn't work but where Raku can tell what you were *trying* to do.

In those cases, Raku will just tell you how to do what you wanted to do.  And, in fact, `\Q...\E` is one such case.  If you'd tried to do it the Perl way

```raku
/\Q$substring\E/
```

you'd have gotten the same answer I gave above (use `$substring` or quotes) in the form of the following error message:

```
Unsupported use of \Q as quotemeta.  In Raku please use: quotes or
literal variable match.
```

So, sometimes, Raku will solve the problem for you!  But that's not something that will happen *all* the time and, any time you're tempted to ask a SO question, it's a good bet that Raku *didn't* answer your question for you.  So here are the steps you'd take in that case:

#### Step 0: check the docs

The first true step should, of course, be to search the [Raku docs](https://docs.raku.org/) for anything useful.  I bet you did this – the docs currently don't [return any relevant results for `\Q..\E`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.raku.org+%5CQ...%5CE). In fact, the only true positive match of `\Q...\E` in those results is from the *Perl to Raku guide - in a nutshell*: "using `String::ShellQuote` (because `\Q…\E` is not completely right) ...". And that's obviously **not** what you're interested in.

The docs website doesn't always yield a good answer to simple questions. Sometimes, as we clearly see with the `\Q...\E` case, it doesn't yield *any answer at all* for the relevant search term.

#### Step 1: Search Stack Overflow

Again, you probably did this, but it's good to keep in mind: You can limit your SO search questions/answers tagged as related to Raku by adding `[raku]` to your query.  Here, a query of `[raku] "\Q...\E"` wouldn't have yielded anything relevant – but, thanks to your question, it will in the future :)

#### Step 2: Archived/historical "spec" docs

Raku's design was written up in a series of "spec" docs written principally by Larry Wall over a 2 decade period.

(The word "specs" is short for "specification speculations". It's both ultra authoritative detailed and precise **spec**ifications of the Raku language, authored primarily by Larry Wall himself, and mere **spec**ulations -- because it was all subject to implementation. And the two aspects are left entangled, and now out-of-date. So don't rely on them 100% -- but *don't ignore them* either.)

The "specs", aka design docs, are a fantastic resource. You can search them using google by entering your search terms in the search box at [design.raku.org](https://design.raku.org/).

---

A search for `\Q...\E` lists 7 pages. The only useful match is [Synopsis 5: Regexes and Rules](https://design.raku.org/S05.html) ("24 Jun 2002 — `\Q$var\E /` ...").  If I click it and then do an in-page search for `\Q`, I get 2 matches that, together, answer your question (at least with respect to variables – they don't mention literal strings):

> In Raku `/ $var /` is like a Perl `/ \Q$var\E /`

> `\Q...\E` sequences are gone.

#### Step 3: IRC chat logs

In this case, searching the design docs answered your question.  But what if it hadn't/we didn't understand the answer?

In that case, searching the IRC logs can be a great option (as previously discussed in the **Quicker answers** section of [an answer to a past Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70942880/1077672). The IRC logs are an incredibly rich mine of info with outstanding search features. Please read that section for clear general guidance.

In this particular case, if we'd [searched for `\Q` in the old Raku channel](https://irclogs.raku.org/search.html?query=%5CQ&type=words&nicks=&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2005-02-26&to-yyyymmdd=2020-04-14), we would have gotten a bunch of useful matches.  None of the first few *fully* answer your question, but several do (or at least make the answer clear) if read in context – but it's the need to read the surrounding context that makes me put searching the IRC logs below the previous steps.

Comment: Note: this answer is based on @raiph's [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70997717), which I split into two questions for better searchability.  raiph, if you'd like credit for this answer (much of which you wrote) please feel free to copy it into a new answer and I'll accept that one instead.

Comment: Please feel free to reuse any of my Raku related content here on SO or anywhere else, as you see fit, republishing it here on SO or anywhere else (eg the docs). Reuse it as is, or edited, or made somewhat or completely unrecognizable as part of something else, it's all more than good. No need for any credit, though if it feels right to you to consider mentioning me after making especially substantive reuse that might be nice on rare/auspicious occasions. 

Comment: A nit. "I get 2 matches that, together, answer your question:" But they don't, cuz they don't mention using a literal string. You're so careless!  (OK, mea culpa.)

Comment: FWIW I had thought I probably ought look at breaking "How do I find answers to Raku questions?" out as a separate community Q+A. But I knew I ought A) research whether I risked incurring the wrath of SO mods by doing so, and, if so, B) decide if I should still go ahead anyway in the hope they didn't notice, or decided to leave it be even if it did arguably transgress SO guidelines about what Qs are acceptable, or at least just closed it rather than deleting it. But now you've improved it maybe that gets added to your infinite todo list rather than mine...

Comment: Thanks, @raiph.  And that makes sense re: the community Q+A – though you should feel equally free to reuse anything I added in creating a community Q+A if your infinite todo list ends up [smaller than mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406525/comparing-infinities#1406546).

Answer (score 2):

The **Raku** version:

```perl
    my $sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
    my $substring = 'quick .*? fox';
    $sentence ~~ s/<$substring>/big bad wolf/;
    say $<>;  #returns: ｢quick brown fox｣␤
    put $sentence;  #returns: The big bad wolf jumped over the lazy dog␤
```

Above, `$<>` is used as an alias for `$/`, the match variable.
Note you can write the third (smartmatching) line as follows--it gives the same result(s):

```perl
    $sentence ~~ s{<$substring>}="big bad wolf";
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_interpolation